# Notification between users Android studio

Tags: android, notifications

I'm working on a small android project and I need help with notifications.
So it's like multiple users are going to use the same device.

Is there a possible way to exchange notifications between users in the same device and with no database? I mean, send the notification according to the username and password?

Comment: while login you need to set which user currently logged in

Comment: i didn't get what you mean
after login there is always a user ID that is transfered through all the application a string that define the actual user.

Comment: is your login functionality online?

Comment: No i connect to a local DB to verify the user name and pwd

Comment: So it means user A logs in, do something, wants to notify user B and leaves. Then user B logs in and receives the notification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have multiple users on the same device on an offline app.

You need first to implement a log in system to log the users. So every time an user wants to use the app he has to log in.

Then you want users to be able to exchange notifications between each other.
So let say user A sends a notification to user B. You just store the notification with the sender as user A and receiver user B. Then when user B logs in you check if there is a stored notification where he is the receiver and display it to him.

It would be easier using a local database but you can achieve that using the Shared Preferences.

You have 2 objects:

- a list of User
- a list of Notification

You can serialise them to a Json file using Gson to store them as a String in the Shared Preferences.

**Notification object**

```
public class Notification{

   public int senderId;

   public int receiverId;

   public String message;
}
```

**User**

```
public class User{

  public int id;

  public String name;

  public String password;
}
```

On log in:

```
List<User> users; // All the users
List<Notification> notifications; // All the notifications
User user; // current user

for(Notification n : notifications){
   if (n.receiverId == user.id){
      displayNotification(n, users)
   }
}


private void displayNotification(Notification n, List<User> users){
   User sender = getUserFromId(n.senderId, users);

   // You can now display a notification like:
   // Sender <sender.name> wants to notifify you about <n.message>
}

private User getUserFromId(int id, List<User> users){
   for(User u : users){
      if (u.id == id)
         return u; 
   }
   return null;
}
```

Serialise/Deserialise the lists:

```
List<Notification> notifications; 
Gson gson = new Gson;
// Serialise
String json = gson.toJson(notifications);

// Deserialise
notifications = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Notification>>(){}.getType());
```